# Given the number of digits for the mantissa and for the exponent, how to I calculate the lower and upper limits?

Tags: floating-point, limit, ieee-754

I've read in a computer science book a few pages about the representation of floating-point numbers (IEEE 754) but I can't figure out how the lowest and highest numbers are calculated as it's not explained.

What's the difference, eventually, between decimal and binary representations?

There's a table with a few examples, I think that it's relative to the decimal representation:

- mantissa: 3 digits | exponent: 1 digit --> lowest value: 10^-12 | highest value: 10^9
- mantissa: 10 digits | exponent: 3 digit --> lowest value: 10^-1009 | highest value: 10^999.

How can I find these results?
And how do I do the same but with binary digits?

Comment: In the second set of sample numbers, if we have a ten-decimal-digit significand (the preferred term, rather than “mantissa”) scaled with the decimal point before it, the significand can represent 0 and numbers from .0000000001 (which is 10^−10) to .9999999999 (almost 1). A three-decimal-digit exponent could represent numbers from 000 to 999. If there is a sign for it, it could be from −999 to +999, representing scales from 10^−999 to 10^+999. With the 10^−10 significand and the −999 exponent, we get 10^−10•10^−999 = 10^−1009…

Comment: … With the .999999999 significand and the +999 exponent, we get .9999999999•10^10^+999, which is almost 10^999.